# How to get the default xmlnamespace from an XML datatype using TSQL?

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath

Consider the following TSQL:

```
declare @xml xml
select  @xml = '<test xmlns="http://this-is-the-default-namespace-uri">some data</test>'

select  x.value('namespace-uri(.)', 'varchar(100)')
from    @xml.nodes('.') x(x)
```

What I'm trying to get from the XML is the URI of the default namespace. This is the value of the `xmlns` attribute on the root element. The above select statement is returning an empty string. How can I get the actual value of the `xmlns`?

Comment: I don't know what is the **context node** for SQL-Server `.node()` function but it's logical that it must be the one holded by `@xml` variable. It might be a document root because of the way you have declared it. The document root doesn't have any in-scope namespace. So, I would give it a try to `@xml.nodes(/*)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with how fn:namespace-uri() works but this seems to return what you want...

```
select  x.value('namespace-uri(.)', 'varchar(100)')
from    @xml.nodes('*[1]') x(x);
```